# so I have this loop but I don't understand what does it do so can someone tell me (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)

Tags: c#

so I saw this syntax in an assignment but I didn't understand the  d[i, 0] = i++ part so can anyone please tell me?

the whole loop is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }
```

Comment: It's assigning `i` to a 2d array `d` at index `i, 0` before incrementing `i`.

Comment: A more common way to see this code written is `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { d[i, 0] = i; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
{
}
```

A `for` loop has four parts:

- Initialisation, performed before any iterations of the loop are done. If empty, no initialisation is done;
- Continuation condition, a condition that must be true in order to execute the body (on *any* iteration, incuding the first). If empty, it's considered true;
- Post-iteration, performed after each iteration (execution of the body). If empty, nothing is done; and
- The body itself. An empty body does nothing.

Hence your loop does the following:

- It creates and initialises `i` to zero. Because it's created here, the lifetime of the variable is limited to the loop;
- It executes the body (empty, so nothing is done) as long as `i` is not greater than `n`;
- For each value of `i`, it sets `d[i, 0]` to `i` and increments `i` as a side effect.

In other words, it sets `d[i, 0]` to `i` for values of `i` between `0` and `n` inclusive.

---

As an aside, because I value seeing as much code as possible on my screen, I tend to prefer something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++) {}
```

But your coding guidelines may not allow for this, at which point I would probably lobby to change the guidelines :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is d: A matrix:

```
d = { d[0,0], d[0,1], d[0,2], ... d[0, m],
      d[1,0], d[1,1], d[1,2], ... d[1, m],
      d[2,0],...
      .
      .
      .
      d[n,0], d[n,1], d[n,2], ... d[n, m]
}
```

where `n` is the number of rows and `m` is the number of columns

So, the loop stores in the first column only the following values:

```
d[0,0] = 0,
d[1,0] = 1,
d[2,0] = 2,
...
d[n,0] = n
```

The rest elements in the matrix are left 0's "the default value of `int`"